# Retornar endereço através da geolocalização

Tags: react-native

No aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo gostaria de colocar um botão que ao ser apertado retorne o endereço atual onde se encontra.

Consegui fazer a parte da geolocalização e consigo obter a latitude e longitude atual do aparelho, e agora o que eu faço? Existe alguma forma que possa me retornar o endereço? Ou terei que abrir um maps ali, buscar pela latitude e longitude, e então retornar o endereço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário utilizar a biblioteca [react-native-geocoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder#install) para realizar a reversão da Latitude e Longitude em endereços.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você já possui a lat e long, então o que você fara agora e a geolocalização reversa, você encontrar isso na documentação da api do google. Abaixo segue um exemplo encontra na APi mesmo.

**Ex: Do código.**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

**Documentação.**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Obs. Esse exemplo e completo com o mapa, mas na api existem algumas formas de você ocultar o mesmo e retornar apenas o endereço.

Comment: O Ex está vazio

Comment: Desculpe, o link quebrou, este está melhor.

Comment: Vou deixar o +1 pois me ajudou no rumo que tenho que buscar, mas oq busco é pra react-native

Comment: Obrigado @Mateus.